# How to choose indexes

Tags: sql, indexing, mariadb

I'm trying to execute several times the following query :

```
SELECT st2.stop_id AS to_stop_id,
       TIME_TO_SEC(
       ADDTIME(TIMEDIFF(MIN(st1.time), %time),
       TIMEDIFF(st2.time, st2.time))) AS duration
FROM   stop_times st1,
       stop_times st2,
       trips tr,
       calendar cal
WHERE  tr.service_id   = cal.service_id
  AND  tr.trip_id      = st1.trip_id
  AND  st1.trip_id     = st2.trip_id
  AND  st1.stop_id     = %sid
  AND  st1.stop_seq +1 = st2.stop_seq
  AND  st1.time        > %time
  AND  DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN cal.start_date AND
  cal.end_date
GROUP BY st2.stop_id
```

However, it run extremely slow. I indexed the following attributes:

```
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name   | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| stop_times |          0 | st_id      |            1 | st_id       | A         |    11431583 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| stop_times |          1 | fk_tid_s   |            1 | trip_id     | A         |     1039234 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| stop_times |          1 | st_per_sid |            1 | stop_id     | A         |       33135 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| calendar   |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | service_id  | A         |        5206 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| calendar   |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | service_id  | A         |        5206 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| trips      |          0 | PRIMARY    |            1 | trip_id     | A         |      449489 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| trips      |          1 | fk_rid     |            1 | route_id    | A         |        1937 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| trips      |          1 | fk_sid     |            1 | service_id  | A         |        7749 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+------------+------------+------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

(For some reasons, `st_id` is not show as a PRIMARY KEY, but it is, I don't know if it's important but just in case..)

I ran SQL EXPLAIN on this query and it gave me the following answer :

```
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys                                   | key                 | key_len | ref                          | rows | Extra                                                               |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | st1   | range  | comp_uniq_st_seq,st_per_sid,comp_uniq_stid_time | comp_uniq_stid_time | 9       | NULL                         | 1396 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | tr    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,fk_sid                                  | PRIMARY             | 8       | reseau_ratp.st1.trip_id      |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | cal   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,comp_sid_date_en,comp_sid_date_st       | PRIMARY             | 4       | reseau_ratp.tr.service_id    |    1 | Using where                                                         |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | st2   | ref    | comp_uniq_st_seq                                | comp_uniq_st_seq    | 14      | reseau_ratp.st1.trip_id,func |    1 | Using index condition                                               |
+------+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------+---------+------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What should I do to get this query running faster?

**EDIT :** 
Query using the requested syntax :

```
SELECT st2.stop_id AS to_stop_id,
       TIME_TO_SEC(
       ADDTIME(TIMEDIFF(MIN(st1.time), %time),
       TIMEDIFF(st2.time, st2.time))) AS duration

FROM   stop_times st1
  INNER JOIN stop_times st2
          ON st1.trip_id = st2.trip_id AND st1.stop_seq + 1 = st2.stop_seq
  INNER JOIN trips tr
          ON tr.trip_id = st1.trip_id
  INNER JOIN calendar cal
          ON tr.service_id = cal.service_id

WHERE  st1.stop_id     =  %sid
  AND  st1.time        >  %time
  AND  cal.start_date  <= NOW()
  AND  cal.end_date    >= NOW()

GROUP BY st2.stop_id
```

Here `SHOW CREATE TABLE stop_times`:

```
CREATE TABLE `stop_times` (
  `trip_id` bigint(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `stop_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `stop_seq` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `comp_uniq_st_seq` (`trip_id`,`stop_seq`),
  KEY `comp_uniq_stid_time` (`stop_id`,`time`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sid_s` FOREIGN KEY (`stop_id`) REFERENCES `stops` (`stop_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tid_s` FOREIGN KEY (`trip_id`) REFERENCES `trips` (`trip_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

For `calendar` :

```
CREATE TABLE `calendar` (
  `service_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`service_id`),
  KEY `comp_sid_date_en` (`service_id`,`end_date`),
  KEY `comp_sid_date_st` (`service_id`,`start_date`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And for `trips` :

```
CREATE TABLE `trips` (
  `trip_id` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `route_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `service_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `trip_headsign` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trip_short_name` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `direction_id` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`trip_id`),
  KEY `fk_rid` (`route_id`),
  KEY `fk_sid` (`service_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_rid` FOREIGN KEY (`route_id`) REFERENCES `routes` (`route_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sid` FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `calendar` (`service_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`st1` needs this composite index: `INDEX(stop_id, time)`

Please use the `JOIN` ... `ON` syntax.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Here is a [Cookbook on creating INDEXes from a SELECT](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

(Edit)

`Calendar` is trickier to handle, and there is no "good" index.  These may help:

```
INDEX(service_id, start_time)
INDEX(service_id, end_time)
```

plus, reformulate `AND  DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN cal.start_date AND cal.end_date` into

```
AND cal.start_date <= NOW()
AND cal.end_time   >= NOW()
```

(Edit 2)

Wherever practical, say `NOT NULL`.  This is probably especially important in `stop_times` which does not have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  Change the two columns in UNIQUE KEY `comp_uniq_st_seq` (`trip_id`,`stop_seq`) to be `NOT NULL` *and* turn it into `PRIMARY KEY (trip_id, stop_seq)`.  This will allow the performance benefits of "the PK is clustered with the data" to kick in.

Now that I see the `CREATE TABLE` for Calendar, and that `service_id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, the two indexes I suggested for it are probably useless.  (Again, this relates to "clustering".)

My [Cookbook for building indexes](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) may come in handy.

Comment: I added what you requested and am currently trying to add a composite index. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I added a composite index on both `stop_id, time` and `trip_id, stop_seq` (unique for this one) and first query is slow, but subsequent queries are indeed faster. I guess the first call is slow because of  `DATE(NOW()) BETWEEN cal.start_date AND   cal.end_date`, should I add an index on these ?

Comment: Well actually it stills slow most of the time. I don't really know what it depends on :o

Comment: (I added an edit.)  Please edit your `CREATE TABLE` to reflect the new indexes.

Comment: I updated `SQL EXPLAIN`, `CREATE TABLE` (and added it for other tables) and the query.

Comment: This is now redundant and can be dropped:  KEY `st_per_sid` (`stop_id`) .  Check for typos in `Calendar` indexes.

Comment: Indeed, I corrected those (but they are still not used in the explain).

Comment: One new index is used - for st2.  The `CREATE TABLEs` bring out another issue; I'll edit my answer soon.

Comment: I wanted to put it as a primary key as you suggest, however it said me it couldn't be a primary key as `trip_id` is a foreign key ! (By the way, I tried following your cookbook, but my range index are strange, and most of the comments that applies where already in your post) (should I delete the foreign key ??)

Comment: I'm not a fan of FKs; I would get rid of it.  Hmmm...  How do you 'compute' `trip_id` when `INSERTing` into `Trips`?  It's not `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: No, it is a set of datas imported from a CSV. It is changed once a month approximately.

Comment: By the way, should I use MyISAM then, if FKs is a bad idea ?

Comment: MyISAM does not handle FKs (and ignores any declarations).  InnoDB is willing to honor FKs, at a cost.  I prefer to fix my code instead of depending on FKs.  Since you are not `cascading`, all you currently get is a check (ie, reach into an index in another table) whenever you `INSERT` a row with a FKs.  (I won't go so far as to say it is a "bad" idea.)  If your CSVs are not 'consistent', the FKs will cause the import to abort.  Does it?

Comment: Assuming the FKs are only checking the CSVs, and assuming the CSVs are complete replacements, I would: `LOAD, do a few `SELECT ... LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL` to check for missing keys, then `RENAME TABLE` to put the new data into place.  _But that is me._

Comment: But since I don't really need these FKs (I only put some because well that's what we learn at college :|), would MyIsam (or Aria) bring me better performances ?

Comment: Currently, InnoDB is regarded as having better performance than MyISAM.  I have no sense of Aria's performance.  (I recommend InnoDB, even without FKs.)

Comment: Thank you, I'm having much better performance now, even if that is still a bit slow.